# Very slow to load images from PHAsset

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

I am using following code to fetch images and AVAsset from PHAsset. Here are two arrays in code :

1. `galleryArr` : to store images for collection view.
2. `mutableDataArr` : store images (for image asset) and videos (for AVAsset) to upload on server

Its very slow to fetch all images from PHAssets array. 
I googled about this, most of people says remove this line [options setSynchronous:YES]; but if I remove this line then completion is called twice and array duplicates the objects (as objects are appended in array within completion).

```
for (int i = 0; i < assets.count; i++) {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;
    options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
    [options setNetworkAccessAllowed:YES];
    [options setSynchronous:YES];

    PHImageManager *manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager;

    PHVideoRequestOptions *videoOptions = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
    videoOptions.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    if (assets[i].mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeVideo) {
        [manager requestAVAssetForVideo:[assets objectAtIndex:i] options:videoOptions resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]])
            {
                [weakSelf.mutableDataArr addObject:asset];
            }
        }];
    }

    [manager requestImageForAsset:[assets objectAtIndex:i]
                       targetSize: CGSizeMake(1024, 1024) //PHImageManagerMaximumSize
                      contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit
                          options:options
                    resultHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
                        if (image) {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                if (assets[i].mediaType != PHAssetMediaTypeVideo) {
                                    [weakSelf.mutableDataArr addObject:image];
                                }
                                [galleryArr addObject:image];
                                if (i+1 == assets.count) {
                                    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                                    [weakSelf.galleryCollectionView reloadData];
                                }



                            });
                        }
                    }];
});


}
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: I have same problem in my app, so i create one thread in `viewdidload` and call this function in background. in completion block i add image in array, after i reload my collectionview.

Comment: The images/videos you fetch may be from iCloud, so it takes more to download.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh no these are not from iCloud

Comment: @PratikPrajapati I can not add this code on viewdidload as these assets are selected from a imagePicker library. I can call this function only in completion of imagePicker.

Answer (score 1):

Just one thought, it looks like you are loading all the images from the array before removing your progress HUD and displaying the gallery. As the number of images could be very large and presuming you are using a collection view or similar, that's quite an overhead before anything is displayed.

I did something like this a while ago and instead of looping through the array and loading everything up front, I let the cells request images as they needed them. This makes it very fast and efficient as cells can display immediately with a loading icon, then flip to the image when it was available. Efficiency comes from only loading images the user is actually going to see.

To make things performant, and by performant I mean I could scroll as fast as I liked without the display freezing, each cell would first check an in memory cache for the image, then trigger a request for an image on a background thread.

When the image was returned, the cell would add it to the in memory cache and then if the cell had not being reused for a different image (due to fast scrolling) it would display the image.

Further, I also used a NSCache for the in memory cache so that if the app started to use a lot of memory, images would be automatically dropped and reloaded the next time a cell wanted one.

The summary is to use a memory aware cache, and only load what you actually need.

Comment: Should I loop through the assets when images and videos  are upload to server?